# help with a printing program

Tags: print-design

i just bought a hp designjet 44 inch photo printer. what printing program would be good too make large prints and help workflow and conserve paper I'm using a macbook pro

Comment: Depends on used colors in printer, used paper and configuration of the printer ... What do you mean with "large prints". Which program do you use for creating the photos/to be printed documents? Please add more infos.

Comment: my friend is a photographer he edits all of his photos in photoshop cc then he puts them on a usb for me. is there a program i can use too enlarge and print them and save space while I'm doing it

Comment: Usually an rip software is used to control the printer. With that software one can manipulate the print jobs.  Enlarging photos is not the best way. Your friend should prepare the photos in the needed quality and size. At last it depends what (I mean the included software like driver etc) you have got with the plotter ..

Comment: ok cool i will look for a rip program and see how i go from there

Answer (score 0):

Preview.app is my tool of choice for large scale printing on a HP DesignJet Z2100 44 inch.

Create your artwork using whatever tools you want and save your print versions of your artwork as a PDF.

Then use Preview's print settings Paper Size options to create and save some custom print sizes you'll commonly use (40x20, 36x40, etc.). Make sure to take into account paper margins.

Then select the appropriate paper size, and let Preview scale the print up/down and let the print driver automatically handle trimming off white spaces, etc.

Then print.